# How to set an object to a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, json, regex, webpack, configuration

I'm doing some work to edit a configuration file.  When I try, things are not quite working right.

Here's my code

```
config.module.rules.unshift( {
        test: "/ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\]icons[/\\][^/\\]+\.svg$/",
        use: [ 'raw-loader' ]
    }
);


fs.writeFileSync("C:\\temp\\config.txt", JSON.stringify(config) );
```

This outputs a file that contains the following text...

```
{
    "test": "/ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\]icons[/\\][^/\\]+.svg$/",
    "use": [
            "raw-loader"
           ]
},
```

however the value of "test" is incorrect.  I'd like to have it set to

```
{
    test: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\]icons[/\\][^/\\]+\.svg$/,
    use: [ 'raw-loader' ]
}
```

Notice how there are no quotes around the regular expression string.

If I try to use

```
config.module.rules.unshift( {
        test: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\]icons[/\\][^/\\]+\.svg$/,
        use: [ 'raw-loader' ]
    }
);


fs.writeFileSync("C:\\temp\\config.txt", JSON.stringify(config) );
```

Here's what I get instead

```
{
    "test": {},
    "use": [ "raw-loader" ]
},
```

I need to get the value of test to be

```
/ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\]icons[/\\][^/\\]+\.svg$/
```

Comment: JSON doesn't support serializing regular expressions. You need to save it as a string, then use `new RegExp()` to convert it to a regular expression after you parse the JSON.

Comment: Don't forget that you have to double all the backslashes when you write a regexp as a string.

Comment: You can use `String.raw` if you don't want to double everything

Comment: To clarify, the JSON isn't the main thing here.  I'm using that to visualise what's happening.   It's the object itself that's the important thing, I need to be sure that it's set properly, and at the moment, I can get everything except the value that I need.

Comment: Just tried String.raw       config.module.rules.unshift(
        {
            test: String.raw(/ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\]icons[/\\][^/\\]+\.svg$/),
            use: [ 'raw-loader' ]
        }
    );     but that gives an error, Guess I'm not using that correctly

Answer (score 0):

I'm barking up the wrong tree.   As people have pointed out, the JSON Serialiser is changing the output to {}, instead of the value I was expecting.    When I look at the object itself.  It's set properly.